Setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable from launchSettings.json of DockerCompose project only
Problem Statement
I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API backend solution with multiple projects that runs using docker-compose in Visual Studio 2022. I have defined several profiles in my launchSettings.json of my DockerCompose project which relates to Development, Staging and Production environments of appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json. I want to make my docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml constant without duplicates for each environment and only change the environment from the profile in the launchSettings.json.
One of the reasons that I don't want to replicate those files is that I don't want to replicate .env files either, instead I want to change all of that in one file which is launchSettings.json for the DockerCompose project.
Attempts
This section illustrates what I have tried, and it should be noted that all of this didn't work additionally to combinations of those trials.
Adding environmentVariables property:
I have tried to add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the environmentVariables property in launchSettings.json for DockerCompose project as follows:
{
    ...
    "commandName": "DockerCompose",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    ...
}

Adding DockerfileRunArguments property:
I have tried to add the aforementioned property as follows:
{
    ...
    "commandName": "DockerCompose",
    "DockerfileRunArguments": "--build-arg=ENVIRONMENT=Staging",
    ...
}

with this in the Dockerfile before the ENTRYPOINT:
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

Adding commandLineArgs property: I have tried to add the aforementioned property as follows:
{
    ...
    "commandName": "DockerCompose",
    "commandLineArgs": "-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging",
    ...
}

Commenting docker-compose.override.yml file and moving the environment to the docker-compose.yml file
I have tried to comment out everything and moved the environment in the docker-compose.yml as follows:
networks:
  backend:

services:
  web-api-1:
    container_name: web-api-1
    depends_on:
      - web-api-n
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi1
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-api-1/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - XXXX:XXXX

Resources
This section includes any resource that could help with understanding the problem
Solution structure:
.
└── solution/
    ├── class-lib-1/
    │   └── files
    ├── class-lib-2/
    │   └── files
    ├── class-lib-n/
    │   └── files
    ├── web-api-1/
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── properties/
    │   │   └── launchSettings.json
    │   ├── appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json
    │   └── Dockerfile
    ├── web-api-2/
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── properties/
    │   │   └── launchSettings.json
    │   ├── appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json
    │   └── Dockerfile
    ├── web-api-n/
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── properties/
    │   │   └── launchSettings.json
    │   ├── appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json
    │   └── Dockerfile
    └── docker-compose/
        ├── launchSettings.json
        ├── docker-compose.yml
        └── docker-compose.override.yml

File samples:
I will provide samples of profiles used in Development and Staging:
{
  "profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "commandVersion": "1.0",
      "composeLaunchAction": "LaunchBrowser",
      "composeLaunchServiceName": "web-api-1",
      "composeLaunchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "serviceActions": {
        "web-api-1": "StartDebugging",
        "web-api-2": "StartWithoutDebugging",
        "web-api-n": "DoNotStart"
      }
    },
    "Staging": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "commandVersion": "1.0",
      "composeLaunchAction": "LaunchBrowser",
      "composeLaunchServiceName": "web-api-1",
      "composeLaunchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "serviceActions": {
        "web-api-1": "StartDebugging",
        "web-api-2": "StartDebugging",
        "web-api-n": "StartDebugging"
      }
    }
  }
}

docker-compose.yml sample:
networks:
  backend:

services:
  web-api-1:
    container_name: web-api-1
    depends_on:
      - web-api-n
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi1
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-api-1/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - XXXX:XXXX

...
...

docker-compose.override.yml sample:
services:
  web-api-1:
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: $ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
    ports:
      - "XXXX"

...

Dockerfile sample which follows the default template of .NET 8.0:
# See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE XXXX

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["web-api-1/web-api-1.csproj", "web-api-1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./web-api-1/web-api-1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/web-api-1"
RUN dotnet build "./web-api-1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build/web-api-1

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./web-api-1.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish/web-api-1 /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/web-api-1 .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "web-api-1.dll"]

Remarks
I have successfully managed to do that using a classic .env file but I don't want to change over and over or replicate it, and I want a way that interacts with Visual Studio.
I hope that I have presented the problem correctly and thanks in advance
